# ruby-debug-ide failed to build gem native extention in Windows

Tags: ruby, intellij-idea, ruby-debug-ide

I have installed debase, but when I try to gem install ruby-debug-ide, it still failed to build gem native extention:

```
ERROR:  Error installing ruby-debug-ide-0.6.1.beta2.gem:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/ruby.exe mkrf_conf.rb
Installing base gem
Unable to resolve dependency: user requested 'debase (> 0)'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:439:in `resolve_for_zero'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:350:in `resolve_for'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:196:in `resolve'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:358:in `resolve'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:473:in `resolve_dependencies'
C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:373:in `install'
mkrf_conf.rb:35:in `rescue in <main>'
mkrf_conf.rb:28:in `<main>'

rake failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.6.1.beta2 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.2.0/ruby-debug-ide-0.6.1.beta2/gem_make.out`}
```

I really have installed debase.

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
actioncable (5.0.0.1)
actionmailer (5.0.0.1)
actionpack (5.0.0.1)
actionview (5.0.0.1)
activejob (5.0.0.1)
activemodel (5.0.0.1)
activerecord (5.0.0.1)
activesupport (5.0.0.1)
arel (7.1.1)
bigdecimal (1.2.6)
builder (3.2.2)
bundler (1.12.5)
coffee-rails (4.2.1)
coffee-script (2.4.1)
coffee-script-source (1.10.0, 1.8.0)
concurrent-ruby (1.0.2)
debase (0.2.2.beta8)
debase-ruby_core_source (0.9.1)
debug_inspector (0.0.2)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (2.7.0)
globalid (0.3.7)
httpclient (2.8.2.2)
i18n (0.7.0)
io-console (0.4.3)
jbuilder (2.6.0)
jquery-rails (4.2.1)
json (1.8.1)
loofah (2.0.3)
mail (2.6.4)
method_source (0.8.2)
mime-types (3.1)
mime-types-data (3.2016.0521)
mini_portile2 (2.1.0)
minitest (5.9.0, 5.4.3)
multi_json (1.12.1)
nio4r (1.2.1)
nokogiri (1.6.8 x64-mingw32)
pkg-config (1.1.7)
power_assert (0.2.2)
psych (2.0.8)
puma (3.6.0)
rack (2.0.1)
rack-test (0.6.3)
rails (5.0.0.1)
rails-dom-testing (2.0.1)
rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3)
railties (5.0.0.1)
rake (11.2.2, 10.4.2)
rdoc (4.2.0)
sass (3.4.22)
sass-rails (5.0.6)
soap4r (1.5.8)
sprockets (3.7.0)
sprockets-rails (3.1.1)
sqlite3 (1.3.11 x64-mingw32)
test-unit (3.0.8)
thor (0.19.1)
thread_safe (0.3.5)
tilt (2.0.5)
turbolinks (5.0.1)
turbolinks-source (5.0.0)
tzinfo (1.2.2)
tzinfo-data (1.2016.6)
uglifier (3.0.1)
web-console (3.3.1)
websocket-driver (0.6.4)
websocket-extensions (0.1.2)
```

What should I do to solve the problem? Do I need to install a specific version of debase?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I finally managed to solve this:

1. Download the source from https://github.com/ruby-debug/ruby-debug-ide
2. Edit `ruby-debug-ide.gemspec` and remove the line `spec.extensions << "ext/mkrf_conf.rb" unless ENV['NO_EXT']`
3. `gem build ruby-debug-ide.gemspec`
4. `gem install ruby-debug-ide-0.6.1.beta8.gem`

Comment: Great!! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that the ruby executable was installed in a directory which had a space in its absolute path. Reinstalling in another location fixed it instantly. Ruby 2.6.something, windows.